# Having Trouble Arranging HTML Elements

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a form with a number of labels and input controls. They won't necessary fit within a tabular form because the columns do not line up in each row.

So, for example, it may look something like this:

```
Label1:  Label2:             Label3:
[Input1] [Input2           ] [Input3             ]

Label4:          Label5:
[Input4        ] [Input5           ]

Label6:          Label7:             Label8:
[Input6        ] [Input7           ] [Input8 ]
```

The biggest issue is that I want the label to always be left-aligned with the input control. Can anyone make some suggestions as to the best way to style this? An existing example would be perfect!

Techniques I've considered include using a table, floating `<div>`s, and combinations of the two. I'm getting close but it's a lot of markup and I'm not confident that it's a good way to approach all browsers.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest that you should find the best structure for your form first before jumping into any design using CSS. The reason is that you'll be compromising users who doesn't have / disabled their CSS. See [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

## Think of this way:

1. Am I making a tabular data? No? Then it's probably just a **list** of `<label>` and `<input>` pairs
2. Should they be listed by order? Then use `<ol>` No? Then use `<ul>`.
3. Are ALL these lists related to each other? No? then wrap them inside a `<fieldset>` not `<div>`s
4. Do they work and look ok even without any images or CSS? No? then Iterate from step 1.

### Some things to consider:

1. `<table>` should only be used for tabular data, not for any layout. See [Why tables for layout is stupid](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/).
2. `<input>` and `<label>` are by default both an inline-level element, meaning, they will align on each other automatically. So using `float:left` or `display: inline-block` will not help, but rather create another problem you'll have to deal later on.
3. `<div>` *(also `<span>`)* should always be a **last option**. See [Semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics).

### Example:

In order for you to picture them out, here's the output:

#### Markup without CSS:

[image: Markup without CSS]

#### Markup with CSS:

[image: Markup with CSS]

#### The *Semantic* Markup:

```
<form action="" method="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Title of this set: </legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for="input1">Label1: </label>
                <input type="text" id="input1" size="31" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="input2">Label2: </label>
                <input type="text" id="input2" size="31" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="input3">Label3: </label>
                <input type="text" id="input3" size="31" />
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Title of this set: </legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for="input4">Label4: </label>
                <input type="text" id="input4" size="31" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="input5">Label5: </label>
                <input type="text" id="input5" size="31" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="input6">Label6: </label>
                <input type="text" id="input6" size="31" />
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Title of this set: </legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for="input7">Label7: </label>
                <input type="text" id="input7" size="31" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="input8">Label8: </label>
                <input type="text" id="input8" size="31" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="input9">Label9: </label>
                <input type="text" id="input9" size="31" />
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

#### The CSS Code:

```
ol {
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
fieldset {
    border: 0;
}
input {
    display: block;
}
legend {
    display: none;
}
```

### Further notes:

1. We included a `size=31` because it will, *at least* accommodate more *viewable* space for users who input data in the field.
2. The `<form>` remains usable even when the CSS is not available or turned off.
3. The `<legend>` helps the user understand the relation of the fields on each other.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'm still working through this. Note that all data *is* related. So it seems like there would be only one `<fieldset>` tag. May I ask how you'd start a new row/line in that case?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, if that's the case, then you will need to set a width for the <form>, so the <li>s will just go down in a new line when the <form>'s width isn't enough to accomodate it. 
Then if you think the <li>'s width is too long, then you can just adjust them accordingly using CSS' width property as well. If all else fail, then use class names on these lists (or <li>).

Answer (score 2):

Make your labels [`inline-block`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock) elements, and give them a width that matches the associated inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to wrap each row of inputs in its own div, then individually wrap each input and label in ITS own div, making it easy to left align the labels.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5zNHj/24/

Comment: Yeah, probably so. I thought of a similar method, but it just seems to be more the kind of thing where you're tricking the browser into doing what you want, rather than writing it in a way the browser is meant to read it. Either one works, it just depends on which way you prefer to operate. Your idea is great though, nice and compact.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I quickly worked through using CSS and a little basic HTML knowledge. Might not be the prettiest way to do it, but it's definitely fast to code out. I've added comments in the code to explain myself (hopefully) relatively clearly. Feel free to ask any questions and I'll try to help you out, even though I'm still a beginner. Good luck! http://jsfiddle.net/Cwca22/Z2ySD/